# TypeScript compile error from @types folder

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

My tsconfig.json file looks like below

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "dist/src",
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/server.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        ".git",
        "node_modules"
    ] 
}
```

When I run *tsc* inside the project folder I get typing errors like below:

> node_modules/@types/express-validator/index.d.ts(23,2): error TS2300:
>   Duplicate identifier 'export='.
>   node_modules/@types/express-validator/index.d.ts(37,28): error TS2374:
>   Duplicate string index signature.
>   node_modules/express-validator/index.d.ts(24,3): error TS2300:
>   Duplicate identifier 'export='.

How can I exclude these errors/files from the output.

Thanks